# Comparison on boolean fields not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `Post` model, with a `posted` boolean field.

I created a new Post, without assigning anything to `posted`.

```
irb(main):012:0> Post.first.posted
  Post Load (9.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

Now, I want to select all posts where `posted` is not equal to `true`.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
irb(main):016:0> Post.where("posted != ?", true)
  Post Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (posted != 't')
=> []
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of how the database treats NULL. Try setting `:default => false` in your migration.

Depending on your database, you might see something like this: (example in MySQL)

```
SELECT 1 = NULL; # returns NULL
SELECT 1 != NULL; # returns NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the table you have created for the Post has the default value for `posted` to be true instead of false.

You could always just select the whole table to see what the value of that `Post` is.  Put this in the console:

```
pp Post.all
```

Comment: But - irb(main):019:0> Post.where("posted = ?", true)
  Post Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (posted = 't')
=> []

Comment: Can you try this instead?: `Post.where(:posted => true)`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that you use sqlite, so this is what docs tell us: "A value with storage class NULL is considered less than any other value (including another value with storage class NULL).". So you can get records with NULL values from database only with WHERE x IS NOT NULL expression.

You should avoid to use boolean fields with possible NULL values. One way to do is declare your fields as not null in migration:

```
t.boolean :f, default: true, null: false
```